# How do smart contract communicate with other?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

As we all know that an external account can send a transaction to smart contract. But I'm confused when it comes to how contracts talk with each other.

> Contracts that exist within the global scope of Ethereum’s state can
> talk to other contracts within that same scope. The way they do this
> is via “messages” or “internal transactions” to other contracts. We
> can think of messages or internal transactions as being similar to
> transactions, with the major difference that they are NOT generated by
> externally owned accounts. Instead, they are generated by contracts.
> They are virtual objects that, unlike transactions, are not serialized
> and only exist in the Ethereum execution environment.[1](https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369)

I fully understand what it mean in the quote. But my question is HOW ? Are there some examples of smart contracts in Solidity show how contracts communicate with each other via "message"?

Comment: Whenever a smart contract calls a function in another smart contract, it does so via a 'message'.

Comment: To add to Jess answer, I would say that the fact that contracts communicate via "message" is just a low-level detail from the point of view of a smart contract developer.

Answer (score 2):

A smart contract is identified with an address on ethereum blockchain. So, you can call it from another by referencing its address.

As far as I know, there is a way to do this:

```
contract CalledContract {
    function doSomething() public {
    }
}

contract CallerContract {
    function callAnotherContract(address addr) external {
        CalledContract called = CalledContract(addr);
        called.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Remember that your called method/function should be public, otherwise you can not call it. If it has external visibility, it can be called only from outside the EVM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Solidity example:

```
contract One {
    function callme() external {
        // ...
    }
}

contract Two {
    // This function accepts as a parameter the address for a deployed
    // instance of the One contract.
    function callOne(One one) external {
        // call the function callme() on our instance of One
        one.callme();
    }
}
```